# How to rotate the control in wpf from the end position of previous rotation

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created one user control  with grid panel.I have one button to rotate this Grid clock wise..It is working..But when I click again the button, it rotates from the beginning, instead of for position of end of previous rotation
Please help me how to rotate the control form continue instead of restarting from the original position. My User Control Xamal :

```
<UserControl x:Class="Floorsreen.FloorUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="600" Background="Yellow">

    <Grid Width="600" Height="600" Background="Yellow" >    
        <Grid Width="500" Height="500" Background="Wheat" Name="my_grid" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform x:Name="transform"  />                 
            </Grid.RenderTransform>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="20"  />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="20"  />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            </Grid>     
        </Grid>
        <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="516,582,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

My UserControl code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;


namespace Floorsreen
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for FloorUserControl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class FloorUserControl : UserControl
    {
        public FloorUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
            DoubleAnimation rotateAnimation = new DoubleAnimation()
            {
                From = 0,
                To = 90,
                Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.0))
            };
            Storyboard.SetTarget(rotateAnimation, my_grid);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(rotateAnimation, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"));

            storyboard.Children.Add(rotateAnimation);
            storyboard.Begin();
        }
    }
}
```

And my Main page xamal:

```
<Window x:Class="Floorsreen.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:view="clr-namespace:Floorsreen" 
        Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="1000">

    <Window.Resources>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <view:FloorUserControl />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Do not set From and To. Set By instead, and read the documentation!

Comment: Thank you it is working

Answer (score 0):

```
DoubleAnimation rotateAnimation = new DoubleAnimation()
        {
            From = 0,
            To = 90,
            Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.0))
           ...//
```

This is where you explicitly specify the behavior you do not want. You need to create an animation, but then reuse the same animation, modifying it with `By` logic, rather than creating a new animation, with hardcoded initial `To` and `From` values that work only for 25% of 90 degree rotations.

Alternately, when properly reusing your animation object, you can access the `To` property, which will be the endpoint of the previous rotation, set a new `From` to the old `To`, and a new `To` to the new `From + 90`. If the old `To` was 360, you can make the `From` and `To` 0 and 90 respectively, like in your current implementation, resetting the process.

A final option, is to have the old `DoubleAnimation` object visible in the event handler, from which you read its `From` and `To`, which will then inform the `From` and `To` of a new `DoubleAnimation` that you freshly construct, in the fashion your code currently employs. Next handle, the new animation object is regarded as the old, and the process repeats.

[Property Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.animation.doubleanimation?view=netframework-4.7.2)